# Is it possible to edit the emulated scene in hololens emulator

Tags: augmented-reality, hololens, hololens-emulator

I don't have hololens yet so i'm planning to use the hololens emulator. Problem is, i don't see any documentations for making your own room in the emulator. I just need a table and some kind of plate to be recognized by the hololens.
Is it possible ?

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/using_the_hololens_emulator

Answer (score 1):

The HoloLens emulator comes with 5 premade rooms that it can emulate for developing against.  Here is a screeenshot of where you configure it and where it is available:

[image]

There are tables and beds in numerous of these scenes already.  You can create your own rooms but you need a HoloLens to do it, or you would need to take an existing mesh and modify it in a 3d modeling tool.

Comment: So you can edit a xef file or make one from a mesh file ? I don't find any 3d modeling tool to do that. It looks like Kinect studio can open them but i'm not sure it's the same xef files, i will dig into that. Thank you for your time.